# pandas deprecated warning to_dict()

Tags: python, pandas, deprecated

I'm getting this deprecated warning:

```
Using short name for 'orient' is deprecated. Only the options: ('dict', list, 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index') will be used in a future version. Use one of the above to silence this warning.
```

when using any of thise lines:

```
df.to_dict('records')
df.to_dict(orient='records')
df.to_dict(orientation='records')
```

pandas v1.1.3
python v3.7.1

Comment: hmm, first and second raise error?

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L1477) and also the warning I'd expect that `'records'` would not trigger this warning. Also I wonder why `orientation=...` would be a valid keyword argument here. Without running the code I'd expect an error on your third line.

Comment: @Amir (Sorry) The question is why is the warning raised. As far as I understand the warning, I should not use df.to_dict(orient='records') but just df.dict('records') which is what I did

Comment: @NiklasMertsch yes not recieving an error from the third line puzzled me as well.

Comment: I get the expected results on my installation: `orientation` throws an error, `'records'` and `orient='records'` work fine, `'orient='r''` causes the described warning and also works.

Answer (score 9):

Warning says that "`orient`" is deprecated. use it like this:

`df.to_dict('records')`

Instead of using `orient=''`, use any of these directly `('dict', list, 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index')`, like:

`df.to_dict('dict')`

`df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: that's exactly what I assumed, the warning message would say. But df.to_dict('records') still raises the warining

Answer (score 5):

I was confused with the same warning. Later I found I used "record" instead of "records". In any case, you can insert `print(orient)` line in the file "pandas/core/frame.py" at a line near 1485 right before the warning.

Comment: 'records' instead of 'records' doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning when I used this code line: `df.to_dict('records')` but when I tried `df.to_dict(orient = 'records')`, the warning went away.